# how can i specify different pypi sources between a project and dependencies of the project

Tags: python, pypi

I build a pypiserver in my computer and uploaded a project,then i tried to install this project in another computer,but i uploaded source of the project without dependencies.

so when i install this project pip try to install all dependencies from my own server.

then:`Error: Not Found for url: http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/simple/gunicorn/`

so,is there some way to specify the project in my own pypiserver and dependencies to two diffrent pypi source when i use `pip install -i my-pypi-server`?

Comment: Can you show your `pip.conf`?

Comment: index-url = http://pypi.douban.com/simple

[install]
trusted-host=mirrors.aliyun.com

Comment: so `pypi.douban.com` is where you have hosted your project source?

Comment: no, it is a mirror in china. i use my ip in  ```pip install -i xxx```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can specify [`--extra-index-url`](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/pip_wheel/#cmdoption-extra-index-url) when you run `pip install` so that the project dependencies can be resolved outside your local repository:

```
pip install -i my-pypi-server --extra-index-url pypi.douban.com/simple <library>
```